# p:panelGrid table-layout: fixed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to have fixed column widths using `<p:panelGrid>`. Therefore, I added

```
<p:panelGrid style="width:100%; table-layout: fixed">
```

and

```
<p:column style="width: 200px;">
```

however the width attribute does not apply. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `columnClasses` attribute to set the style for each column.

```
<p:panelGrid columnClasses="column1,column2,column3,column4" columns="4" style="width:100%">
    <p:column></p:column>                        
    <p:column></p:column>
    <p:column></p:column> 
    <p:column></p:column> 
</p:panelGrid>
```